# Query Stuck in Suspended mode with IO_Completition as Wait Type

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, tempdb, sql-execution-plan

I am running a query in SQL Server 2008r2, it is stuck with

**Task State: Suspended** (Sometimes changes to Running but mostly Suspended)

**Wait Type: IO_Completion.**

There is another query running on the tempdb at the same time.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you cancel the query or is is truely stuck in an IO operation? That would point to a faulty disk (which is unlikely by itself).

Comment: I can run the query manually in SQL Server Management studio, but when it is run as part of my desktop program (in c#), it hangs... My desktop program runs very few queries, all of which can be run quickly if I do them manually on management studio

Comment: What happens in management studio if you run the query while one of those other ones is running?

Comment: If a query does a lot of IO that's what it will show in the wait type while it's running. It doesn't necessarily mean it's stuck. You say it sometimes shows as RUNNING. This tells me it is not actually stuck.

Comment: There may be many reasons why a query runs different from the SSMS vs. the app. If you give more details, we may be able to help. For starters, what is the query you are running?

Comment: I am running a large Merge query (10 joins) while running some simple select queries at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to a join returning too many rows as intermediary results.

I changed the join order and forced the query to run in that order, it solved the problem.